# Home network issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, network-shares, wimax

I have a laptop, a TV which supports LAN connections, and a WiFi phone on my network. The Internet connection is provided from a USB WiMAX modem.

Until last week I was getting the Internet to each device through the laptop: I configured WiFi ad-hoc between the laptop and the phone, and a cabled LAN connection between the TV and laptop. I then shared the WiMAX connection with the ad-hoc network. It worked fine for me.

Recently I've bought a Zyxel P660HTW2 EE ADSL2 modem + router. I now want to configure the router for getting the Internet from the laptop (not from the phone line) via WiFi or an Ethernet connection, then share it to other devices via WiFi or Ethernet.

To be clear, I want to provide internet from `Local Are Connection 2` to router, via `Local Are Connection` or `Wireless Network Connection`.  Tried network bridge, it doesn't help. Also, when laptop connects to second - router network, can't access to **router** by 192.168.1.1 ip. When laptop connects via ethernet cable, can't acces to **router and internet**

[image]

How can I get this working?

Comment: I can assume you're talking about W7 here by the looks of the screenshot, but it would be nice you would confirm this.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes. it's w7. Downvoter trolls, what's wrong with my question?

Comment: are you still there @m0skit0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up Internet Connection Sharing. In Vista (I'm assuming the procedure hasn't changed too much 7), you need to:

1. Connect laptop to Internet. I think you can use WiFi if you want, but maybe not.[1]
2. Take the router that everything else will connect to, and connect it to your laptop **via Ethernet**. WiFi will not work for this connection.
3. Right-click the connection to the Internet, and select Properties. From there, go to the sharing tab, and check the box allowing users to access the Internet connection. Set the connection it is shared to as the one to the router in step 2.
4. Open the router settings (probably by going to 192.168.1.1 in your browser[2]), and set it so that it

   - is not acting as a DHCP server[3]
   - has an IP address different from the one your laptop now has.
5. Reboot the router, and restart the connection to it.
6. Cross your fingers. If I gave you the right steps, it should work as you want it to now.

[1] Also, keep in mind that the less WiFi and the more Ethernet you use, the faster your connection will be. Your access may be fast enough that it doesn't matter, but I know that mine isn't.

[2] If it isn't 192.168.1.1, you may have to jump through a few more hoops.

[3] You probably ought to make sure you can do this before going through with steps 1–3. Some routers don't let you do this, I think.

Comment: can we chat with you via skype or any im else?

Comment: Ok it worked well. now one more thing i want to know. is there any way to share internet connection to both wifi and ethernet adapters?

Comment: I don't think so. What I would do is connect your laptop to the Internet port on the router in step 2 and then you can connect via WiFi to the router, or via Ethernet to the Ethernet ports on the back.

Comment: We can set up a chatroom on SU's chat facilities if you want to, but it sounds like you got it.

Comment: I mean every time i need to change sharing setting?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/340038/sharing-internet-via-cable-and-wifi-connection

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment, "I mean every time i need to change sharing setting?"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1444/discussion-between-zpletan-and-tural-teyyuboglu)